# Return only the first instance of an item in a list of 2-tuples - Python

Tags: python, list, element

Let's say that I have the list:

`[(1,2), (3,4), (1,4), (2,5), (3,10), ...]`

I want to be able to grab only the 2-tuples which have the first instance of the first number; as an example:

`Grab (1,2), Grab (3,4), Ignore (1,4): 1 is already the first entry in the (1,2) tuple, Grab (2,5), Ignore (3,10): 3 is already the first entry in the (3,4) tuple`

I'd like it to return back a list of those tuples, like this:

`[(1,2), (3,4), (2,5), ...]`

And so on

How would I achieve that?

Also, please mind that I'm new to Python - so please supply some code with any helpful answers, as that'll help me learn :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could keep a list of first elements that you've already seen, and grab everything with a first element that isn't on that list. Assuming your list is called `my_list`, we'll iterate through it and put the tuples in a new list.

```
seen = [] # starts empty
new_list = []
for x in my_list:
    if x[0] not in seen:   # if I haven't seen the first element yet...
        new_list.append(x) # grab this tuple!
        seen.append(x[0])  # and remember that now I've seen this first element.
```

Comment: It works beautifully, thank you! I didn't really have an idea of where to start (I couldn't manage to break down this problem into code), but your solution gave me a good idea of how I could solve similar problems! Again, thank you!